# Sparql to find all connected URIs in a graph

Tags: sparql

Let's say I have this data:

```
<http://foo/toast> <veg:two> <http://foo/id_A>  .
<http://foo/apple> <veg:one> <http://foo/id_A>  .
<http://foo/banana> <veg:one> <http://foo/id_A>  .
<http://foo/banana> <veg:two> <http://foo/id_B> .
<http://foo/mango> <veg:one> <http://foo/id_B>  .
```

How would I query that data using the URI http://foo/apple , to get any resource connected to the same object that a `<http://foo/apple> <veg:one>` is conncted to. Like in `<http://foo/apple> <veg:one> <http://foo/id_A>`

I'm expecting the query to return:

```
 <http://foo/toast> , <http://foo/banana> , <http://foo/mango>
```

I tried queries like this, but they didnt work:

```
SELECT * WHERE{
<http://foo/apple> ?p ?id .
?fr  (<veg:one>)*/(<veg:two>)*  ?otherId .
}
```

I'm not sure how to connect back a property path to ?id .
Should I UNION the query with an inverse path back ? That seems like overkill and that there is probably an easier way

I can create a query to get back the toast and banana URIs, but not the mango URI

Thanks !

Comment: I think you need the inverse path operator `^` for the second part of the property path.

Comment: Can you clarify the link that you're trying to follow?  You say that you're looking for subjects connected to a triple, but that doesn't make a while lot of sense ; a resource is related to other resources, not triples.  Are you just asking for a path to apple's id that traverses veg:one and veg:two in either direction?

Comment: I'm trying to find any resource related to the object of some subject and predicate I supply. So yes, I'm asking for a path to apple's id that traverses veg:one and veg:two in either direction. That should be toast, banana and mango. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you, it sounds like you want resources that have a path beginning with veg:one or veg:two, and end at apple's id by following veg:one or veg:two backward and forward again.  If that's correct,  then it would look like

```sql
#--    [[  fruit -> id  ]/[   id -> fruit  ]]*
:apple ((veg:one|veg:two)/^(veg:one|veg:two))* ?other .
```

Comment: Oddly, I selected just ?other using your path, but I only get back <http://foo/id_A>   as  ?other in the result set

Comment: Almost there, it gets : <http://foo/toast> , <http://foo/banana> , <http://foo/apple> . The only one it doesnt get is the http://foo/mango